# How to handle calculated fields in otherwise bound forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

This concerns an approval field on a form. In the database, it's a bool field, an int field containing a FK to approvers, and a date-time field that, together, indicate whether something was approved and if so, who approved it and when. On the form, this has to translate into something like "Approved by John Smith on 01/02/03 04:05."

I handle this with a navigation bar. When the binding source position changes, the event is trapped and the code formats the calculated fields, like this (what the code does it not that important).

```
private void ctlNavBar1_displayCurrent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var drv = talsBindingSource.Current as DataRowView;
    if (drv != null)
    {
        ctlBoundCheckButton1.lblText = $"Submitted {drv.Row.Field<DateTime>("SubmitDate").ToString("MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt")}";
        ctlBoundCheckButton1.setControls(true);
        if (drv.Row.Field<bool>("Approved"))
        {
            var sup = talsSupervisorsBindingSource.Current as DataRowView;
            ctlBoundCheckButton2.lblText = $"Approved by {sup.Row.Field<string>("FullName")} on {drv.Row.Field<DateTime>("ApproveDate").ToString("MM/dd/yy")}";
            ctlBoundCheckButton2.setControls(true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (DialogCenteringService centeringService = new DialogCenteringService(this))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No TALs to Approve", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that

```
public TALsApprove()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    talsTableAdapter.FillForApproval(timeTrackDataSet.TALs, User.ID);
    usersTableAdapter.FillBySupervisor(timeTrackDataSet.Users, User.ID);
    timeSlipsTableAdapter.FillBySupervisor(timeTrackDataSet.TimeSlips, User.ID);
    ctlNavBar1.displayCurrent += ctlNavBar1_displayCurrent;
    ctlNavBar1.bindingSource = talsBindingSource;
    // this assignment doesn't fire Position Changed (or anything else, as far as I can tell)
}
```

the binding source event PositionChanged does not fire when the binding source is first assigned. I've worked around that by using the form Shown event, like this.

```
private void TALsApprove_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctlNavBar1_displayCurrent(null, new EventArgs());
}
```

So my questions are:

1.- Does calling event handlers directly like this mess with any of .NET's internals? (e.g. memory leaks, stack problems, etc.)

2.- Is there a less kludgy way of handling the calculation of fields when the binding source is first initialized, as well as when the contents of the current record change? I experimented with the binding source events CurrentChanged and CurrentItemChanged, but they seem to over-fire, firing even when no actual field value had changed.

Comment: Side point, life gets easier if you work with strongly typed datarows instead of datarowviews, i.e. `var r = (talsBindingSource.Current as DataRowView).Row as TALsRow` then you can just `r.SubmitDate` ratehr than `drv.Row.Field<DateTime>("SubmitDate")`

Comment: *they seem to over-fire, firing even when no actual field value had changed* - yes, if you read the description for the CurrentChanged event it says something like "fires when the value of bindingsource.Current changes". bs.Current is a pointer to "the active record". If the user ha s 10 rows in the grid and clicks on the fifth row the bs.Current changes to be the fifth row. If they click on the 7th row, Current changes to the 7th row. If they click Next Next Next in an associated navigator, then the active row will be the 10th and 3 navigations occurred to get there so CurrentChanged fires 3x

Comment: Same for CurrentItem; that one fires when a nav occurs that changes the current row OR also when a property of the  current row is edited. you *wanted* the edit, but are observing/complaining about the "fire when nav occurs" which these events both do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I might think to tidy this up:

1 ) Use a calculated column

Assumptions:

- You have a strongly typed DataSet with two tables like Applications and Users
- You have the following columns in Applications: Approved(bool), ApproveDate(datetime), ApprovedByUserId(int)
- You have a single datarelation between Applications and Users that maps Applications.ApprovedByUserId (many) to User.UserId (one), and UserId is also an int

Process:

- In your dataset click in your Applications table, and add a string column
- Set its Expression property to something like: `IIF([Approved] = False,'Not approved','Approved by' + Parent.Username + ' on ' + [ApproveDate])`

[image]

You have some process alreadythat fills good data into the table:

[image]

When you run the app it becomes the datatable's problem to build the narrative:

[image]

Let's edit another detail in at runtime:

[image]

When you finish the edit and move off the row it will be committed to the table and the narrative updates automatically

You can read more about what syntax you can use in [DataColumn.Expression](https://www.bing.com/search?q=datacolumn+expression&cvid=a68a1e0fe4a54a40ae8ea7c2a40cbfaa&aqs=edge..69i57j0j69i59l2.3196j0j9&FORM=ANAB01&PC=U531)

If you don't have a bool approved you could add one or use some other test like `IIF(ApprovedByUserId IS NULL,'Not Appproved,'App...'). If yo uhave multiple datarelations coming off Applications you specify the name of the relation after Parent like` Parent(App_User).UserName` assuming the datarelation is called App_User

---

2. Bind different things on the UI

Noone ever said you only had to bind Text. If you had a "Approved" bool column in your dataset, you could have several labels in a row:

```
--label1----- --label2------ --label3-- --label4--
"Approved by" BindParentName " on "     BindDate
```

You can bind every one of their Visible properties to the Approved bool so the labels disappear if the user navs to an unapproved row.

The easiest way to get the parent user name into the Applications data table (because all these labels are bound to a indingsource that sits on the Applications table, right?) is to use an `Expression` on a new column like above, but simpler (just `Parent.UserName` or Parent(App_User).UserName`) to import the user name into the Applications datatable.

There are other ways, involving multiple binding sources that bind to datarelations.. We can even jiggle a combo box into doing it - the combo has a DataSource of the users table, but a DataMember of "ApprovedByUserId" from the applications table; it will perform 2 way lookup of the `ApprovedByUserId <--> UserId` equivalence